# Is it possible to use the Goolge ARCore camera sharing feature in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

The Google ARCore documentation for Android describes how to share the camera access with ARCore (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/camera-sharing).

Is there a way to use this feature from inside Unity? 
The documentation does not contain any hint.

Comment: Why do we need camera sharing feature?

Comment: For example if we want to share our live camera view

Comment: is it means to share AR Core stream? For example I have 2 devices on first device I start AR session and on second device I see exactly the same screen like on first device?

Comment: Yes, that could be a use case

Comment: But, how the data will be shared between two devices? By Bluetooth?

Comment: One could think of a lot of possibilities how to share a video stream between devices. That is not part of my question, though ;)

Comment: "The SharedCamera class allows the app to share control of the camera with ARCore and obtain image readers and surfaces for rendering. Images can be read concurrently while ARCore is running or while ARCore is paused." from google doc.